# Is this a bug in the C++ conditional_variable?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, locking

The following is the source code in the header file of conditional_variable of C++5.2.1. I wonder whether there is a problem in the first *wait*, where the *while* testing is not in a critical section of *__lock* waked from *wait* again.

```
 template<typename _Lock, typename _Predicate>
 void wait(_Lock& __lock, _Predicate __p) {
     while (!__p())
         wait(__lock);
 }

template<typename _Lock>
void wait(_Lock& __lock) {
    shared_ptr<mutex> __mutex = _M_mutex;
    unique_lock<mutex> __my_lock(*__mutex);
    _Unlock<_Lock> __unlock(__lock);
    // *__mutex must be unlocked before re-locking __lock so move
    // ownership of *__mutex lock to an object with shorter lifetime.
    unique_lock<mutex> __my_lock2(std::move(__my_lock));
    _M_cond.wait(__my_lock2);
 }
```

Comment: Look up what `_Unlock` does.

Comment: it just call the unlock`explicit _Unlock(_Lock& __lk) : _M_lock(__lk) { __lk.unlock(); }`

Comment: And what about the destructor?

Comment: Yes you are right, I ignored the destructor， the *__lock* is re-locked there！

Answer (score 1):

Not a bug. When `!__p()` is evaluated the mutex in `__lock` is supposedly still locked by current thread.

I suppose the code is from libstdc++.

Comment: When the upper *wait* is called by the user, the *__lock* is held, but the *__lock* is released in the bottle *wait* before the actual blocking, and the *__lock* is not re-locked when the thread is awake to evaluate the __p() again. Is there anything wrong?

Comment: In source of libstdc++, i found the destructor of `_Unlock` trying to relock the mutex.